# Some objects missing after importing a .shp into PostGIS

Tags: postgis, shapefile

I have a .shp file which I am trying to import into a PostGIS database using the "PostGis SHP and DBF Loader". This works smoothly but some (maybe 5%) of the records have an empty geometry field. (I have double checked the original files and there should be geometry on every row). I can't see anything special about these rows - it appears random but presumably isn't.

Can anyone tell me why this might happen?

Comment: No error output?

Comment: No, it just says: 

Shapefile type: Polygon
Postgis type: MULTIPOLYGON[2]
Importing shapefile (2346 records)...
Creating spatial index...

Shapefile import completed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to be completely sure, if you are using pgAdmin to have a look at the resulting table, be careful because sometimes the geometry fields appear to be empty when in fact they aren't. This is probably due to pgAdmin having trouble showing big geometries.

You can check the geometries doing a query like:

```
SELECT ST_NPoints(the_geom) FROM your_table;
```

or opening the layer in program like QGIS and see if all the features are drawn.

Comment: Aha! I think you might be on to something there. The "empty" geometries have >2000 points. How can I get around this?

Comment: Why get around it? The geometry is there. The only thing you are missing is seeing a lot of numbers and letter in a row, that will make no sense. pgAdmin is just avoiding to show it because it will just take a lot of bandwith to send it from the db.

Comment: I am trying to get data from PostGIS in GeoJSON form. It returns an empty string for the problem rows. Meaning that, while the geometry is technically there, it's not much use to me!

Comment: Ok, strike that! It returns an empty string in PGAdmin but works fine otherwise...which makes sense! Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, I've found myself in this situation too. That's why I always prefer to work on the command line with psql.

Comment: Yeah, that's something I want to get into the habit of but I've only been using PostgreSQL for a week though so a GUI is pretty helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure geometries are valids?
You probably should test them before the import.

If the error persists, try to test them with SQL.

> ALTER TABLE mytable   ADD CONSTRAINT
>   geometry_valid_check  CHECK
>   (ST_IsValid(the_geom));

You can read more about that in paragraph *4.3.5. Ensuring OpenGIS compliancy of geometries* on http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ch04.html

edit : Qgis command for validity check : Vector > Geometry Tools > Check geometry validity

Comment: Ah, good call. I'm checking it now. It's a 115MB file so it's going to take some time.

Comment: 6% done...and no errors so far. This is going to take ages. The data was originally a MapInfo .tab. I converted it to .shp in order to import it. I have converted it back to .tab without any problems and all shapes display correctly in MapInfo and QGIS so it would seem they are valid...

Comment: It would *seem* only! GIS desktop softwares are able to display geometries even if they are invalids. If you don't have time to work on the full dataset, get a sample containing a least few shapes that ended-up with no geometry in postgis and check for their validity

Comment: Yeah I see what you're saying but I think amercader has nailed it. Thanks all the same!